# what should I add in DIR and PROJECT_DIR in run_example.sh for it to work in allrank using windows 10

Tags: python

I use windows 10 and I run the run_example.sh in docker. I want to use learning to rank loss functions in allrank. run_example.sh has an example on how to run the loss functions. I have installed allrank using pip install. I get an error in DIR and PROJECT_DIR because of syntax. I don't know what I should add in the two variables for the file to work. Please help. run_example.sh has code shown below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIR=$(dirname $0)
PROJECT_DIR="$(cd $DIR/..; pwd)"

docker build -t allrank:latest $PROJECT_DIR
docker run -e PYTHONPATH=/allrank -v $PROJECT_DIR:/allrank allrank:latest /bin/sh -c 'python allrank/data/generate_dummy_data.py && python allrank/main.py --config-file-name /allrank/scripts/local_config.json --run-id test_run --job-dir /allrank/test_run
```